# How to generate multiple response.write:s with json in node.js/express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Having some trouble with generating multiple response.write:s from an api call in node.js. Here is the code.

```
 // get the articles
app.get('/api/articles', function(req, res) {


res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
});
// use mongoose to get all feeds in the database
Feed.find(function(err, feeds) {
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after     res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    feeds.forEach(function(feedModel) {
        //for each feed in db get articles via feed-read module
        feed(feedModel.url, function(err, articles) {
            articles.forEach(function(articleModel) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(articleModel));//works!!
                res.write(JSON.stringify(articleModel));//doesnt produce output.
            });
        });
    });
}); //end find function
res.end();
}); //end api call
```

Comment: Hi! After some tinkering I got it to work by removing the res.writeHead and res.end lines. Apparently I will trigger two writeHead with the previous code and by removing the lines node or express will "automagically" fix the headers.

Comment: I got the idea from to post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628052/nodejs-console-log-works-but-response-write-doesnt

Answer (score 1):

You need to `end()` inside the callback no at the end.

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(articleModel));
```

Comment: Ok. tried that. Now the first feed actually shows up but not the rest. I am thinking thats because we actually end prematurely before we are done processing the rest of the feeds? how would I merge all the articleModels in a list then just using the one res.end statement to send the respond back?

Comment: Then you'll need [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), or a mechanism to manage callbacks. But that is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I got it to work by removing the res.writeHead and res.end lines. Apparently I will trigger two writeHead with the previous code and by removing the lines node or express will "automagically" fix the headers.
/Stefan

Comment: I got the idea from to post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628052/nodejs-console-log-works-but-response-write-doesnt